Stereo view using RealityView in iOS 18
Im trying to make a VR Stereo 3d view using RealityView And SwiftUI in iOS 18
Issue: Both sides are not connected together meaning when the 3d item on the left view moves I do not see the one on the right moves same way or moves at all
Expected: Both Sids Should Move together in Sync with a single user move
here is my code so far,
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var box = AnchorEntity()
  @State var box2 = AnchorEntity()

  @State private var rotateTime: Timer!

  @State var rotateCounter: Float = 0.0

  var body: some View {
    
    HStack {
        RealityView{ content in
            
            let item = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: .init(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)), materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .white, isMetallic: false)])
            box.addChild(item)
            // rotate box on x and y 45 degrees
            box.transform.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi / 4, axis:[0,1,1])

            content.add(box)
        }

        RealityView{ content in
            content.add(box.clone(recursive: true))
        }

    }
    .background(.black)
    .onAppear(){
        
        // After 5 Sec the animation starts
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 5.0)
        {
            //-- Run Rotation Loop ----
            rotateTime?.invalidate() // to make sure no instance for it before
            
            rotateTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                rotateMe()
            })
        }
    }
}

func rotateMe(){
    
    rotateCounter += 1
    
    if rotateCounter > 360 {
        rotateCounter = 0.0
    }

    box.transform.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: (rotateCounter * (.pi / 180)), axis: [0,1,0])
  }
}

When the code starts it will wait for 5 sec then start to try animation for the left view box



I have already edited this post to be focusing on one question only and I'm waiting for a fair review and resubmitting as it contains a very needed answers to those who fetching for a resolution for this task specifically.

Everything works fine if each anchor entity is unique.
Also, iOS 18/iPadOS 18 Simulator doesn't work properly.
Use a device!
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var anchor1 = AnchorEntity()
    @State var anchor2 = AnchorEntity()
    @State var rotateTime: Timer!
    @State var rotateCounter: Float = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            RealityView { rvc in
                let item = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.5), 
                                  materials: [SimpleMaterial()])
                anchor1.addChild(item)
                anchor1.orientation = .init(angle: .pi/4, axis:[0,1,1])
                rvc.add(anchor1)
            }
            RealityView { rvc in
                let item = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.5), 
                                  materials: [SimpleMaterial()])
                anchor2.addChild(item)
                anchor2.orientation = .init(angle: .pi/4, axis:[0,1,1])
                rvc.add(anchor2)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                rotateTime?.invalidate()
                rotateTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(
                    withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                        rotate(anchor1)
                        rotate(anchor2)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        .background(.black)
    }
    func rotate(_ anchor: AnchorEntity) {
        rotateCounter += 1
        
        if rotateCounter > 360 { rotateCounter = 0.0 }
        
        anchor.orientation = .init(angle: (rotateCounter * (.pi/180)), axis: [0,1,0])
    }
}


Thanx @ Andy Jazz, Yes everything works fine if it's separated but that means if I have a long codes I need to rewrite it all in the other view and also if I use a game controller or a key to move an entity it should be altered to be able to move two entities at the same time, I was hoping that I could make the Content or rvc of the first RealityView to update the Content or rvc of the 2nd RealityView so I would be able to do actions on one side only and it would automatically reflect on the other side too like what we normally could do in SceneKit and ARKit, Is that possible ?

I have added another reply which partially solve the problem of doubling the code but I faced another issue that now I still control each view separately and I t is weird  I guess user interaction is different from view still in VR the only chance is to control thru a GameController cause the iPhone would be on your eyes so It's ok to control two views same time the only problem now I 'm facing is How to do it?

When I try to move the anchor using a Game Controller it did exactly the same, and it moves only one box not both and this is a weird action cause it is the same variable and it should act together

Thanks to Andy Jazz, I have edited the reply to allow a one RealityView but I still failed to control both views at same time, now I have added a drag option but it work on each view separately and a double-click to stop animation and restart it also it works separately Still need to work on how to make the control sync together and the I will check if the collision would work in sync too
here is the code
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
        MainView()
        MainView()
    }
    .background(.black)
  }
}


struct MainView : View {
  @State var anchor1 = AnchorEntity()
  @State var rotateTime: Timer!
  @State var rotateCounter: Float = 0.0

  @State var animateMode = false

  @State var position: UnitPoint = .zero

  let ratio: Float = 0.005

  var body: some View {
    RealityView { rvc in
        let item = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.5), materials: [SimpleMaterial()])
        anchor1.addChild(item)
        anchor1.orientation = .init(angle: .pi/4, axis:[0,1,1])
        rvc.add(anchor1)
    }
    .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            rotateTime?.invalidate()
            rotateTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(
                withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                    rotate(anchor1)
                }
            )
        }
    }
    .gesture(dragThis)
    .gesture(doubleClickThis)
}

func rotate(_ anchor: AnchorEntity) {
    rotateCounter += 1
    
    if rotateCounter >= 360 { rotateCounter = 0.0 }
    
    anchor.orientation = .init(angle: (rotateCounter * (.pi/180)), axis: [0,1,0])
}

var dragThis: some Gesture {
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 15, coordinateSpace: .global)
        .onChanged { value in
            print(value.translation)
            print(value.location)
            
            anchor1.position.x = Float(value.translation.width + position.x) * ratio
            anchor1.position.y = Float(value.translation.height + position.y) * -ratio
            
        }
        .onEnded{value in
            position.x += value.translation.width
            position.y += value.translation.height
        }
}

var doubleClickThis: some Gesture {
    TapGesture(count: 2)
        .onEnded { value in
            animateMode.toggle()
            
            if animateMode {
                rotateTime?.invalidate()
                rotateTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(
                    withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                        rotate(anchor1)
                        //rotate(anchor2)
                    }
                )
            }
            else
            {
                rotateTime?.invalidate()
            }
        }
  }
}

Since in VR we cannot touch the screen so here is the code with a control by both touch and using a Game Controller
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import GameController

struct ContentView : View {
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        MainView()
        MainView()
    }
    .background(.black)
}
}


struct MainView : View {
@State var anchor1 = AnchorEntity()
@State var rotateTime: Timer!
@State var rotateCounter: Float = 0.0

@State var animateMode = false

@State var position: UnitPoint = .zero

@State var gameController: GCController!

@State private var stickTime: Timer!

@State var SRDelayer = false

let ratio: Float = 0.005

var body: some View {
    RealityView { rvc in
        let item = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.5), materials: [SimpleMaterial()])
        anchor1.addChild(item)
        anchor1.orientation = .init(angle: .pi/4, axis:[0,1,1])
        rvc.add(anchor1)
    }
    .onAppear {
        setupGameController()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            rotateTime?.invalidate()
            rotateTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(
                withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                    rotate(anchor1)
                }
            )
        }
    }
    .gesture(dragThis)
    .gesture(doubleClickThis)
}

func rotate(_ anchor: AnchorEntity) {
    rotateCounter += 1
    
    if rotateCounter >= 360 { rotateCounter = 0.0 }
    
    anchor.orientation = .init(angle: (rotateCounter * (.pi/180)), axis: [0,1,0])
}

var dragThis: some Gesture {
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 15, coordinateSpace: .global)
        .onChanged { value in
            print(value.translation)
            print(value.location)
            
            anchor1.position.x = Float(value.translation.width + position.x) * ratio
            anchor1.position.y = Float(value.translation.height + position.y) * -ratio
            
        }
        .onEnded{value in
            position.x += value.translation.width
            position.y += value.translation.height
        }
}

var doubleClickThis: some Gesture {
    TapGesture(count: 2)
        .onEnded { value in
            animateMode.toggle()
            playStop()
        }
}

func playStop() {
    if animateMode {
        rotateTime?.invalidate()
        rotateTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(
            withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                rotate(anchor1)
                //rotate(anchor2)
            }
        )
    }
    else
    {
        rotateTime?.invalidate()
    }
}

//MARK: - GameController

func setupGameController() {
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidBecomeCurrent, object: nil, queue: nil, using: didConnectController)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidStopBeingCurrent, object: nil, queue: nil, using: didDisconnectController)
    
    GCController.startWirelessControllerDiscovery{}
    
    guard let controller = GCController.controllers().first
    else
    {
        return
    }
    registerGameController(controller)
    
}

func didConnectController(_ notification: Notification) {
    
    gameController = notification.object as? GCController
    
    print("Game Controller ◦ gameControllerIsConnected \(gameController.productCategory)")
    
    unregisterGameController()
    
    registerGameController(gameController)
}

func didDisconnectController(_ notification: Notification) {
    
    gameController = notification.object as? GCController
    print("◦ disgameControllerIsConnected \(gameController.productCategory)")
    
    unregisterGameController()
}

func registerGameController(_ gameController: GCController) {
    
    self.gameController = gameController // important for refresh screen
    
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.dpad.left.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("Left", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.dpad.up.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("Up", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.dpad.right.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("Right", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.dpad.down.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("Down", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.buttonX.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("Square", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.buttonY.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("Triangle", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.buttonB.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("Circle", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.buttonA.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("Cross", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.buttonOptions?.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("Options", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.buttonMenu.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("Menu", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.leftThumbstickButton?.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("LeftThumbClick", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.rightThumbstickButton?.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("RightThumbClick", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.leftShoulder.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("LeftShoulder", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.rightShoulder.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("RightShoulder", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.leftTrigger.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("LeftTriggerClick", pressed)}
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.rightTrigger.pressedChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.button("RightTriggerClick", pressed) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.leftTrigger.valueChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.triggerL("LeftTriggerValue", value) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.rightTrigger.valueChangedHandler = { (button, value, pressed) in self.triggerR("RightTriggerValue", value) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.leftThumbstick.valueChangedHandler = { (button, xvalue, yvalue) in self.sticks("LeftThumbStick", xvalue, yvalue) }
    gameController.extendedGamepad?.rightThumbstick.valueChangedHandler = { (button, xvalue, yvalue) in self.sticks("RightThumbStick", xvalue, yvalue) }
    
}

func unregisterGameController() {
    
}

func button(_ button: String, _ pressed: Bool) {
    
    if button == "Cross"
    {
        if SRDelayer == false
        {
            SRDelayer = true
            
            animateMode.toggle()
            playStop()
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.0)
        {
            self.SRDelayer = false
        }
    }
    
    
    if button == "Up"
    {
        anchor1.position.y += 0.02
    }
    
    if button == "Down"
    {
        anchor1.position.y -= 0.02
    }
    
    if button == "Right"
    {
        anchor1.position.x += 0.02
    }
    
    if button == "Left"
    {
        anchor1.position.x -= 0.02
    }
}

func triggerR(_ button: String, _ value: Float) {

}

func triggerL(_ button: String, _ value: Float) {
}

func sticks(_ button: String, _ xvalue: Float, _ yvalue: Float) {
    if button == "RightThumbStick" || button == "LeftThumbStick"
    {
        if yvalue > 0.5 || yvalue < -0.5  || xvalue > 0.5 || xvalue < -0.5
        {
            if stickTime == nil // if its not running
            {
                stickTime?.invalidate()
                
                stickTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                    pollInputSticks()
                })
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stickTime?.invalidate()
            stickTime = nil
        }
    }
    else
    {
        stickTime?.invalidate()
        stickTime = nil
    }
}

func pollInputSticks() {
    if let gamePadRight = gameController.extendedGamepad?.rightThumbstick
    {
        if gamePadRight.yAxis.value > 0.5 // Up
        {
            anchor1.position.y += 0.002
        }
        else if gamePadRight.yAxis.value < -0.5 // Down
        {
            anchor1.position.y -= 0.002
        }
        
        if gamePadRight.xAxis.value > 0.5 // Right
        {
            anchor1.position.x += 0.002
        }
        else if gamePadRight.xAxis.value < -0.5 // Left
        {
            anchor1.position.x -= 0.002
        }
    }
    
    if let gamePadLeft = gameController.extendedGamepad?.leftThumbstick
    {
        if gamePadLeft.yAxis.value > 0.5 // Up
        {
            anchor1.position.z -= 0.002
        }
        else if gamePadLeft.yAxis.value < -0.5 // Down
        {
            anchor1.position.z += 0.002
        }
        
        if gamePadLeft.xAxis.value > 0.5 // Right
        {
            anchor1.position.x += 0.002
        }
        else if gamePadLeft.xAxis.value < -0.5 // Left
        {
            anchor1.position.x -= 0.002
        }
    }
}

}

here is the results photos from real iPhone11 with iOS18

With No Control

Using Touches

Using GameController

Your code works flawlessly (including both gestures) on a real iPhone. Don't use Simulator for running your app as it now shows wrong results for the second view.

Thanks @Andy Jazz yes it do run it on a real iPhone with iOS 18 and even I tried it with a MacOS Sequoia and Yes it do run flawlessly but I was hoping that both views can be controlled in sync with only moving either of them they work separately  and when I added a game controller also it moves the first one only not both, anyway I have followed your advice and conclude it in a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79158249/how-to-control-stereo-vr-realityview-with-touch-or-game-controller-in-ios-18-or
