How to make AR working in Stereo RealityView iOS 18 using SwiftUI
I have an issue using RealityView to show two screens of AR, while I did succeed to make it as a non AR but now my code not working.
Also it is working using Storyboard and Swift with SceneKit, so why it is not working in RealityView?
The goal is to see a cube in both sides in Augmented Reality on the iPhone to make an AR/VR view or XR view to use it with VR Box, which is very successful using SceneKit with Swift but now it show only the left side in AR and the right side not moving and a bit small.

Here is my code:
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit


struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack (spacing: 0){
            MainView()
            MainView()
        }
        .background(.black)
    }
}

struct MainView : View {
    @State var anchor = AnchorEntity()

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let item = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size:     0.2), materials: [SimpleMaterial()])

            content.camera = .spatialTracking
            anchor.addChild(item)
            anchor.position = [0.0, 0.0, -1.0]
            anchor.orientation = .init(angle: .pi/4,    axis:[0,1,1])

            // Add the horizontal plane anchor to the scene
            content.add(anchor)
        }
    }
}


RealityView shares its reality scene in the environment. I don’t think it is meant to work with 2. Maybe if you injected a second scene but this will likely be very resource intensive. SwiftUI is meant to work like training wheels. A lot of the lower level stuff is hidden.

So returning back to SceneKit, Swift/ObjC and Storyboard is much more safer those days than using experimental staff like SwiftUI and RealityView?

“Safer” and “experimental” are not terms I would use. SwiftUI is UIKit with training wheels, you get rapid more stable development at the expense of customizations. Like I said before you can try injecting separate scenes instead of using the default. This is what you would do with SceneKit.

Ok I got it now but the question is still remain the same cause even when I try to inject a second separate screen it seems not working with me in SwiftUI I even tried to do it with the AR Scene Kit and it gives worse results as one screen gets totally black, If you know how to successfully inject it then it would be a very helpful to me.

Just gave it a try and RealityKit.Scene doesn't have any accessible initializers so what I was suggesting as a possible workaround isn't possible.

That's why I guess I will return back to the ARSceneKit and storyboard unless there is a little modern way that can start a SwiftUI project and access a storyboard inside it because when I tried the ARSCNView as a UIViewRepresentable it give the black screen on one side so my conclusion that AR need to be in a single SwiftUI Screen or else lets return to the Storyboard ARSceneKit, Anyway thanks for the tries.

AR Stereo view in RealityKit for iOS 18
Since SwiftUI doesn't allow you to create a working clone of RealityView in AR mode, and SwiftUI doesn't allow you to create two separate RealityViews with simultaneous (in-sync) world or planar tracking (due to the fact that you cannot run two AR sessions at once), all you can do is attach your primitives to the AR camera's position (since the camera coordinates are known in each frame without tracking). All you need to do is to provide each AnchorEntity with a .camera case. However, one small trouble awaits you here: in the right view, the cube primitive will be closer to the camera than in the left view. Don't know if this is a bug or not...
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct Controller : View {
    @State var position: UnitPoint = .zero
    @Binding var pose: SIMD3<Float>
    let anchor: AnchorEntity
    
    var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 15, coordinateSpace: .global)
            .onChanged {
                anchor.position.x = Float($0.translation.width +
                                             position.x) * 0.005
                anchor.position.y = Float($0.translation.height +
                                             position.y) * -0.005
                pose = anchor.position
            }
            .onEnded {
                position.x += $0.translation.width
                position.y += $0.translation.height
            }
    }
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            rvc.camera = .spatialTracking
            let box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.25))
            anchor.addChild(box)
            rvc.add(anchor)
            
            anchor.position.z = -1.0
            anchor.orientation = .init(angle: .pi/4, axis:[0,1,1])
        }
        .gesture(dragGesture)
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {
    @State var pose: SIMD3<Float> = .zero
    let anchor1 = AnchorEntity(.camera)
    let anchor2 = AnchorEntity(.camera)

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            VStack {
                Text(anchor1.position.description)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding(20)
                Controller(pose: $pose, anchor: anchor1)
                    .onChange(of: pose) { (_, new) in
                        anchor2.position = SIMD3<Float>(new)
                    }
            }
            VStack {
                Text(anchor2.position.description)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding(20)
                Controller(pose: $pose, anchor: anchor2)
                    .onChange(of: pose) { (_, new) in
                        anchor1.position = SIMD3<Float>(new)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}


P.S.
The problem is that the tracking configuration in the brand-new ARKit's API (for working with RealityViews) is launched globally, and is in no way connected to the view itself (unlike in ARView).
let session = SpatialTrackingSession()

let config = SpatialTrackingSession.Configuration(
    tracking: [.world],
    sceneUnderstanding: [.occlusion],
    camera: .back
)
Task {
    await session.run(config)
}


Solution – ARView in SwiftUI
You can materialize your idea using two ARViews, because as I said earlier, you can run world tracking configuration only if there's just one running session for two views. And in this case, you'll have to implement UIGestureRecognizer inside ARContainer structure to implement gestures.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit

struct ARContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    @State var pose: SIMD3<Float> = [0,-0.5,-1.5]
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let worldAnchor: AnchorEntity
    let session: ARSession

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        arView.cameraMode = .ar
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        arView.session = session
        session.run(config)
        
        let box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.25))
        worldAnchor.addChild(box)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(worldAnchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ arView: ARView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
            worldAnchor.position = pose
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {
    let anchor1 = AnchorEntity(world: [0, 0,-1])
    let anchor2 = AnchorEntity(world: [0, 0,-1])
    let session = ARSession()

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            VStack {
                Text(anchor1.position.description)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding(20)
                ARContainer(worldAnchor: anchor1, session: session)
            }
            VStack {
                Text(anchor2.position.description)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding(20)
                ARContainer(worldAnchor: anchor2, session: session)
            }
        }
    }
}


You are a life saver, apple documents are so complicated not to explain this, but you nailed it, and about the issue of the left camera and right I think really it is a bug but it is affordable we can change the Z for the left bit far I will raise a bug to apple about it may be they can help it next time,

One thing more I notice that there is a fine line between he left and right view and it is effect the view indeed when you put the phone inside the VR box or Google Cardboard the best way is to give HStack (spacing: 0) this would let that line go aways and then everything else would be perfectly aligned and no issue even with or without the safe area in reliers or later  iPhones

I have made a mistake, I get rushed assuming it is working but if you look closer it is not AR it is Static VR with a Background of the camera, The cube have to be remaining in its place while we move the iPhone but that not what happened here

Thanks @Andy Jazz, in fact i am really intending to anchor it to a world coordinates as I was showing in the video of the question, although I think it is possible because I have already made that in ARSCNView many times but with a storyboard. I Thank you again and I wish you can find a solution for it in RealityView meanwhile I will accept your answer as a correct

This is Exactly what I was testing from awhile and it is the best solution regarding SwiftUI, As for RealityView I guess it still new framework and it would take time to implement something like that, Still the issue I raise to apple DTS about that not answered yet and I will inform you with it hopefully they have some hidden solution. Thanks A lot @Andy Jazz, im happy with this result so far. P.S. I edited your answer to import ARKit I guess you must have forgot it when copy and past
